# Customizing excel ribbon using xml code

Tags: xml, excel

Hi i am trying to customize ribbon using xml code but new tab does not show on the tab. This is the code for customUI.xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab id="customTab" label="Makra">
 <group id="customGroup" label="AAA">
 <button id="customButton1" 
 label="SOME LABEL" 
 imageMso="TableSharePointListsModifyColumnsAndSettings" 
 size="large" 
 onAction="BTNA" />
 </group>
 <group id="customGroup1" label="SOME LABEL 2">
 <button id="customButton2" 
 label="AAA" 
 imageMso="CacheListData" 
 size="large" 
 onAction="BTNB" />
 <button id="customButton3" 
 label="SOME LABEL" 
 imageMso="DatabaseMoveToSharePoint" 
 size="large" 
 onAction="BTNC" />
 </group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

and the .rels file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/><Relationship Id="someID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml" /></Relationships>
```

When I modify the file by adding the customUI folder and make changes in -rels file, the tab does not show up... Can anyone hel me with this? Are there any other files that must be mofified? With CustomUI Editor it works well but I don't want to use this tool. Do You think it is safe to use it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier method to achieve what you need, in case that you need your customization settings bounded to the file and not the program (i.e.: will only be available to to that file and not every time you open the program)

Hope that this was what you were searching for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file